# Trigonometry Identities questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given that $\sin\theta =\dfrac15$ and $0<\theta <\dfrac{\pi}2$, without evaluating the angle $\theta$, find the exact value of

$$\sin\left( \frac{\theta}2-\theta \right)\tag1$$

I know that $\dfrac{\pi}2$ is $90^\circ$ and it is on the first quadrant but how do I solve for this question?

Hence simplify

$$\cot \theta \sec \theta+\cos(6\pi+\theta)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-\theta\right)\tag2$$

Comment: What did you try for $1)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**

Using [addition and subtraction formulas for sine](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/SinCosFormula.shtml), we obtain
\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)&=\color{red}{\sin\frac\pi2}\cos\theta-\color{blue}{\cos\frac\pi2}\sin\theta\\
&=\color{red}{1}\cdot\cos\theta-\color{blue}{0}\cdot\sin\theta\\
&=\cos\theta.
\end{align}
Next, use a famous trigonometric identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$.

Comment: Hint for $(2)$, use [addition and subtraction formulas for cosine](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/SinCosFormula.shtml) and the following identities:
\begin{align}
&\color{red}{[1]}\;\;\cos(x\pm y)=\cos x\cos y\mp\sin x\sin y\\
&\color{red}{[2]}\;\;\cot\theta=\frac{1}{\tan\theta}=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin \theta}\\
&\color{red}{[3]}\;\;\sec\theta=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sin{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)}=\cos{\theta}$$
$$\cos{(6\pi+\theta)}=\cos{\theta}$$
$$\cot{\theta}\sec{\theta}=\frac{1}{\sin{\theta}}$$
$$\cos{\theta}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}}$$